# Todo note floats into the wrong margin with page break and TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: floats, margins, todonotes

While writing a seperate document I noticed that the **todo note was printing in the wrong margin**. Initially I thought this was because of a rogue use  of `\reversemarginpar`, but after a bit of playing around I think todo notes is struggling to keep track of which margin it is floating into when it spills over a page. See the example below:

## Todo note is in the wrong margin

[image]

## TeX capacity exceeded

I stumbled across this by chance when I was trying to replicate the problem, and have commented the line out. If this is uncommented:

```
% If you uncomment this line you get a 'Tex Capacity exceeded'.
%\dummysentences{10} \todo{\dummysentences{1}} \dummysentences{2}
```

I get a TeX capacity exceeded error and nothing compiles. I don't know what is causing this and it isn't my primary concern, but nonetheless would be interested if someone can explain it, but I am not sure if it is related or not, or if it warrants its own question.

## My not quite so minimal working example

Unfortunately trying to replicate the problem from my original document was surprisingly difficult, and so I have reduced it is much as I can while still retaining the problem. Ironically, most of what remains, if removed or replaced with lipsum will alleviate the problem (albeit not in my original document!). If someone can replicate this using less then please advise.

```
\documentclass[english,a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Nice headers.
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include figures.
\usepackage{lipsum} % Useful for adding jargon.
\usepackage{physics} % Nice partial derivatives and BRAKET notation.
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize]{todonotes} % A nice TODO list. [disable] to supress.
\usepackage{xspace} % Gives nice spacing for commands.
\usepackage[top=20mm,bottom=20mm,left=20mm, right=30mm, heightrounded, marginparwidth=24mm,  marginparsep=3mm, headsep=10mm]{geometry} % Use nice margins. Does give a small change in the default page margins. 

\setlength{\parindent}{15mm} % Nice paragraph indents.

% Removes hyphenation
\tolerance=1
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\hbadness=10000

\pagestyle{fancy} % The headers and footers.

% Define the dummy sentence, an ancient palindrome.
\def\sator{Sator Arepo tenet opera rotas.\xspace}

% A command to print the sentence repeatedly.
% Argument #1 is the number of times to repeat it.
\newcount\loopcounter
\def\dummysentences#1{%
    \loopcounter = #1
    \loop
    \sator\ %
    \advance\loopcounter by -1
    \ifnum\loopcounter > 0
    \repeat%
}

 
\begin{document}
\clearpage
\noindent
\dummysentences{4}
\begin{align}
a & \approx \sum_{i=0}^{A} \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{A} 
\end{align}

\dummysentences{20}

\subsection{Some filler text}

\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\subsubsection{subsec 1}

\subsubsection{subsec 2}

\subsubsection{subsec 3}

\subsection{Ow noo}

\dummysentences{12} \todo{In the correct margin.} \dummysentences{2}

\dummysentences{10} \todo{argh. and I'm in the wrong margin} \dummysentences{2}

% If you uncomment this line you get a 'Tex Capacity exceeded'.
%\dummysentences{10} \todo{\dummysentences{1}} \dummysentences{2}

Some very interesting text.\todo{I'm where I am supposed to be}, \dummysentences{3} 

\end{document}
```